# redirecting a subdirectory to some other hosting server fluently

Tags: linux, redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect, folder-redirection

I am hosting a server on which I would like to have a `/articles` folder.
I would like to redirect all calls to this name `www.myserver.com/articles` to a wordpress that is being hosted on another server.

How can I do this so that the URL does not show the browser is using a different IP address?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of [this search](http://serverfault.com/search?q=apache+reverse+proxy). We already have many Q&A about reverse proxy technology.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using apache for your web server hosting your `/articles` location you can use *ProxyPassReverse* to achieve what you are after.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

There is an example of setting up directory based reverse-proxy in the documentation.